# Interop c++ struct in c# variable string size

Tags: c#, c++

i transfer over ipc a struct from unmanaged into managed code.
Is it possible to transfer a string without set a constant size
or fill the rest auf the bytes into the last member of the struct ?

**c++ struct**

```
typedef union
{
    struct
    { 
         int id;
         string Data;
    };
    char bytes[];
} SocketData;
```

---

**c# struct**

```
   [StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct SocketData
    {
        public int id;
        public string Data;
    }
```

---

**Convert bytes to struct**

```
public static object RawDeserialize(byte[] rawData, int position, Type anyType)
{
    var rawsize = rawData.Length;
    //if (rawsize > rawData.Length)
    //    return null;
    var buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(rawsize);
    Marshal.Copy(rawData, position, buffer, rawsize);
    var retobj = Marshal.PtrToStructure(buffer, anyType);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
    return retobj;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not do that, `std::string` is not POD.
Even with different compiler/linker versions `std::string` is NOT binary compatible*, you cannot expect it to be compatible between managed and unmanaged world.

* By this I mean, If you have a DLL build using XX compiler version (even of same vendor), and passing `std::string` from a client (EXE), which is built using older/newer compiler/header version - the `string` object may not be same.

Comment: I understand your point. By using char pointer will just transfer a some pointers or not ? Is my question even possible ? I'm from the C# .NET World and its difficult to handle c++.

Comment: You need to do conversion in the C++ code itself. You can have CLI enabled for one or more of your source files. The C++ project would however be dependent on MSCOREE.DLL (Native clients would be ABLE to load it).

Comment: I'know but I can not enable the CLI in my case.

Answer (score -1):

This other post might help you.

It involves [using StringBuilder instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027022/receiving-strings-through-interop).

I wonder why you need variable buffer lengths since Sockets usually use fixed length buffers

Comment: I think my problem is on the c++ side... StringBuilder don't help me. The socket struct is just an example. I need to transfer some detoured data from winsock recv.